Where is the value that is written to the variable rbp, or more precisely to the register rbx?
I have the code and the assembler code of this code in C.

int
mon_backtrace(int argc, char **argv, struct Trapframe *tf) {
    cprintf("Stack backtrace:\n");

    uint64_t rbp = read_rbp();
    uint64_t rip = read_rip();

    while (true) {
        cprintf("  rbp %016lx  rip %016lx\n", rbp, rip);
        print_rip_debug_description(rip);

        rip = *((uint64_t *)rbp + 1);
        rbp = *(uint64_t *)rbp;

        if (rbp == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


and .asm
static inline uint64_t __attribute__((always_inline))
read_rip(void) {
    uint64_t rip;
    asm volatile("call 1f; 1: popq %0"
  804210402a:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   804210402f <mon_backtrace+0x34>
  804210402f:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
        cprintf("  rbp %016lx  rip %016lx\n", rbp, rip);
  8042104031:   49 bf 0f 57 10 42 80    movabs $0x804210570f,%r15
  8042104038:   00 00 00 
  804210403b:   49 be 9f 42 10 42 80    movabs $0x804210429f,%r14
  8042104042:   00 00 00 
        print_rip_debug_description(rip);
  8042104045:   49 bd 99 3f 10 42 80    movabs $0x8042103f99,%r13
  804210404c:   00 00 00 
        cprintf("  rbp %016lx  rip %016lx\n", rbp, rip);
  804210404f:   4c 89 e2                mov    %r12,%rdx
  8042104052:   48 89 de                mov    %rbx,%rsi
  8042104055:   4c 89 ff                mov    %r15,%rdi
  8042104058:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  804210405d:   41 ff d6                call   *%r14
        print_rip_debug_description(rip);
  8042104060:   4c 89 e7                mov    %r12,%rdi
  8042104063:   41 ff d5                call   *%r13
        rip = *((uint64_t *)rbp + 1);
  8042104066:   4c 8b 63 08             mov    0x8(%rbx),%r12
        rbp = *(uint64_t *)rbp;
  804210406a:   48 8b 1b                mov    (%rbx),%rbx
        if (rbp == 0) {
  804210406d:   48 85 db                test   %rbx,%rbx
  8042104070:   75 dd                   jne    804210404f <mon_backtrace+0x54>
}
  8042104072:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  8042104077:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  804210407b:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  804210407c:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
  804210407e:   41 5d                   pop    %r13
  8042104080:   41 5e                   pop    %r14
  8042104082:   41 5f                   pop    %r15
  8042104084:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  8042104085:   c3                      ret

0000008042104086 <monitor>:
    cprintf("Unknown command '%s'\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}

I have a code, it reads from memory to the variable rbp (register rbx)
        rbp = *(uint64_t *)rbp;
  804210406a:   48 8b 1b                mov    (%rbx),%rbx

In essence, I need to find the machine instruction in the assembler code that wrote the value in the first line to the memory cell.
Exactly to this cell, exactly this value.
In other words, I want to know which assembler instruction put a value into the rbx register. Or how to find this instruction?
Also I found
static inline uint64_t __attribute__((always_inline))
read_rbp(void) {
    uint64_t rbp;
    asm volatile("movq %%rbp,%0"
  8042104027:   48 89 eb                mov    %rbp,%rbx
}


That's not a (valid) .asm file. It looks like interleaved disassembly. It's also not clear what you're asking.

Your assembly is missing the first two lines, the cprintf("Stack backtrace:\n");    uint64_t rbp = read_rbp(); which is where you should see rbx being assigned.

If you are looking who put the value into memory, that will likely be in the calling function (or in the function prologue of the mon_backtrace that you did not show).

Note that fetching rip via a call in inline asm is broken on x86-64; because the ABI provides for a red zone, inline asm must not push anything onto the stack.  (x86-32 used to do it that way, as there was no alternative, but it also didn't have a red zone.) Fortunately, x86-64 also has rip-relative addressing modes, so you could simply do asm("lea 1f(%%rip), %0; 1:" : "=r" (rip)).  Using asm volatile is also pointless here.
